# »Ich hätte gern« + Partizip II in Bedeutung von »ich möchte gern«

Tags: grammar, regional

Oft höre ich am Telefon folgenden Satz:

> Guten Tag, ich hätte gern den Herrn Müller gesprochen.

**Fragen:**

1. Ist diese Form im ganzen deutschsprachigen Raum verbreitet oder regional?
2. Gehört diese Form dem Hochdeutschen oder ist es eher Dialekt / Umgangssprache?
3. Kann sie allgemein in dieser Bedeutung benutzt werden? (*Ich hätte jetzt gern ein Bier getrunken.*) oder beschränkt sich deren Nutzung nur auf gewisse Situationen oder Floskeln?

Comment: Da es nicht Teil der Fragen ist, antworte ich zu einem Nebenaspekt hier in einem Kommentar: neben a) _den Herrn Müller_ hört man auch b) _Herrn Müller_, c) _den Müller_, e) _Müller_, f) _einen Herrn Müller_, g) _einen gewissen Herrn Müller_. Diese Referenzen unterscheiden sich bzgl. Branche, Region, Förmlichkeit, Höflichkeit, Eindeutigkeit und den Bekanntschafts- und Vertraulichkeitsverhältnissen zwischen Anrufer, Angerufenem und Herrn Müller. Das wäre mglw. eine eigene Frage wert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Verwendet wird dies im gesamten deutschsprachigen Raum, allerdings ist es
2. Umgangssprache!
3. Tatsächlich schränkt sich die Nutzung dieser umgangssprachlichen Form hier ein:

`"Ich hätte jetzt gerne ein Bier getrunken."` kann nicht anstelle von

`"Ich möchte jetzt gerne ein Bier trinken."` verwendet werden (noch nicht einmal umgangssprachlich), da es eine unterschiedliche Bedeutung hat:

Der erste Satz ist im Konjunktiv, und heißt z.B. Wenn nicht etwas dazwischen gekommen wäre, hätte ich gern... Also wenn es möglich gewesen wäre, hätte ich gern... (Möglichkeitsform).

Der zweite Satz (ist vermutlich klar), drückt einen Wunsch aus.

Comment: Ich halte das (speziell die Frage am Telefon) nicht für Umgangssprache - Das ist ein korrekter Satz. Das implizite "wenn er denn erreichbar wäre" (weil ich am Telefon eben nicht sehen kann, ob er da ist)  ist halt weggelassen.

Comment: Würde man die Frage so stellen (nicht in Umgangssprache), würde man ja davon ausgehen, dass Herr Müller nicht da ist. Ein Telefonat so zu beginnen, macht überhaupt keinen Sinn. Was sollte man damit auch erreichen wollen? Sich beschweren, dass man ihn ja eigentlich sprechen will, aber er ja dummerweise nicht da ist?

Comment: Ich sehe das so: Sprache ist durchaus öfters mal nicht logisch. Wo sie's nicht ist, ist sie aber nicht automatisch deswegen Umgangssprache. Das war der einzige Grund für meine Bemerkung.

Comment: "Ich möchte" ist auch Konjunktiv.

Comment: Den Satz `Ich hätte jetzt gerne ein Bier getrunken.` kann man einerseits als Bedauern verstehen im Sinne von `Schade, ich hätte jetzt gerne ein Bier getrunken.` Dann aber auch als Wunsch, er ließe sich ohne weiteres einer Kellnerin sagen, sie würde ihn als Bestellung werten.

Comment: @tofro: Es gibt ziemlich viele denkbare Fortsetzungen. EIne davon: "wenn er denn so gütig wäre, meinen Anruf entgegenzunehmen". Ich beobachte diesen (übertriebenen) "Höflichkeitskonjunktiv" auch bei anderen Formulierungen, wie *Dürfte ich eine Frage stellen?*, wo doch *darf* eher angebracht wäre.